# How to deduce the atmospheric mixed time-space domain energy cycle formulae, and where can Arpe et al. (1986) be found?

Tags: meteorology, energy

[image: Mixed space-time domain formulation of the energy cycle]

(Where can I know) How these formulae in the figure (Ulbrich and Speth, 1991), called mixed space-time domain formulation of the energy cycle, were deduced?

And the reference Arpe et al. (1986), I can not find it on internet, could anyone find it?

Arpe, K., Brancovic, C., Oriol, E., Speth, P., 1986: Variability in time and space of energetics from a long series of atmospheric data produced by ECMWF. Beitr. Phys. Atmos., 59, 321-363.

U. Ulbrich and P. Speth, 1991: The global energy cycle of stationary and trasient atmospheric wave: results from ECMWF anayses. Meteorol. Atmos. Phys. 45, 125-138.